# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Component Info

Tags: javascript, java, android, xml, android-studio

**I'm trying to make a simple app with my website right now and once I run it. I just get an error!I am using **Android Studio 1.5.1**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.rejoicedanceministry.rejoicedance/org.rejoicedanceministry.rejoicedance.MainActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
at org.rejoicedanceministry.rejoicedance.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
at org.rejoicedanceministry.rejoicedance.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
at org.rejoicedanceministry.rejoicedance.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:172)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
at org.rejoicedanceministry.rejoicedance.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**This is my coding!
First this is the MainActivity.java**

```
package org.rejoicedanceministry.rejoicedance;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://rejoicedanceministry.org");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }});


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();

        /** Setting a share intent */
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    /** Returns a share intent */
    private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Convert Website to Android Application");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT," Vist www.AndroidWebViewApp.com if you Want to Convert your Website or Blog to Android Application");
        return intent;
    }


}
```

**My second one is the Splash.java**

```
package org.rejoicedanceministry.rejoicedance;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Splash extends Activity {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        Thread t =new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(10000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent i =new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

**Third One: MyAppWebViewClient.java**

```
package org.rejoicedanceministry.rejoicedance;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("rejoicedanceministry.org")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Now I'm to the XML files: content_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity_splash.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/vert_loading"
    tools:context=".Splash" >


</RelativeLayout>
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:title="@string/share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
</menu>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Rejoice Dance</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="share">Share</string>
    <string name="action_websearch">Web search</string>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.rejoicedanceministry.rejoicedance" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**This is styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**And last: styles.xml (V21)**

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**I am new to this and I am learning, but I have no clue how to fix this error? Any suggestions and help?**

Comment: Where is the `CoordinatorLayout` in your XML ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what that is. I'm new to coding. Where do I find that? @Sparta

Answer (score 1):

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.`

Your need to use a theme that extends from the ones provided by the appcompat library, which should be in your project anyway if you're using the design library.

Your styles.xml file should have something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"> <!-- or Theme.AppCompat.Light -->
    <!-- customize the theme here -->
</style>
```

Make sure in your AndroidManifest that the `<activity>` tag uses this theme. Or set the theme on the `<application>` tag and leave it off the `<activity>` tag. Finally, your Activity class should extend AppCompatActivity, not Activity directly.

Comment: I updated my AndroidManifest above and added styles and styles (v21) and its still not working

Comment: @AlejandroO you shouldn't need styles-v21, you can extend these themes on all platform levels (they get compiled into your app because they are in the appcompat library).

Comment: ok I get that, but It still doesn't work. What do I have to do? I am new to coding sorry!

Comment: @AlejandroO Are you getting the exact same exception? Or is it something new?

Comment: I am getting the same one